# Can someone tell me why my table is transparent?

Tags: html, css

I have a site that I'm working on which I need the table to have a background that is not transparent.

```
  <li>
            <div> some code </div>

    <div style="height:110px;" class="tableOwner">
        <img style="margin-top:30px;float:left;" src="/newimg/ClickShare.png"></img>

        <table border="0" class="tableShare" style="background-color:white !important;">
            <tbody style="background-color:white">
            <tr>
                <td><span class='st_sharethis' displayText='ShareThis' style="float:left;"></span></td> 
                <td><span class='st_facebook' displayText='Facebook' style="float:left;"></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span class='st_twitter' displayText='Tweet' style="float:left;"></span></td>
                <td><span class='st_blogger' displayText='Blogger' style="float:left;"></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span class='st_googleplus' displayText='Google +' style="float:left;"></span></td>
                <td><span class='st_linkedin' displayText='LinkedIn' style="float:left;"></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><span class='st_pinterest' displayText='Pinterest' style="float:left;"></span></td>
                <td><span class='st_email' displayText='Email' style="float:left;"></span></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
</li>
```

Unfortunately no matter what I do, whether I make table,tbody,or td have background-color:white ... the background always shows as transparent. The class in span tells the browser where to fetch a PNG image, but other than that, the background of the table should be white and not transparent.

Help!

Comment: Can you reproduce this on jsFiddle?

Comment: I'll give you the site that I'm working on dev.bidsthatgive.us . When you click on Click to share! button at the bottom of any auction, you will see the table is transparent. Instead it should overlay on top of the next auction item. Sorry if the source is messy, this is a client and I did not build the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i've tried this in firebug and it works for me.

apply this css to the table

```
.tableShare
{
position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Took me 10 minutes to come up with the same solution, only to find you posted it =)

Answer (score 1):

your table have no content; it make the table have no size; look: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZyWJk/)

```
//you content on <td> or <span>

...<td><span class='st_sharethis' displayText='ShareThis' style="float:left;"> your content here </span></td>..
```

Comment: There shouldn't be any content. Class st_sharethis will build content when the script is ran.

Comment: you need to provide the script too, unless you're done with this.